# Way to update all Readme(s) of Guithub Repo with changed styling

Tags: git, github

As given [here](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/#headings) ,Github has changed the way to show smnallest heading from 3 Pound symbols to  <s>Four</s>  Six Pound symbols . I am looking for some way to update all my Readme(s) of the repos that I have.

Eg: https://github.com/HackersArena/python-backdoor (In the last part of the read-me)

Also reference linking has changed as you can see here:

Eg: https://github.com/TilakMaddy/gulp-template-backend-support (Broken page links)

I am looking for any sort of *Git - command -built - in- Migration* technique
to update all the readme(s) ?

Comment: Question Updated / Edited due to Typo

Answer (score 0):

Well, to address your question: updating of the content isn't really in git's wheel house.  Depending on your environment, a combination of Unix (or git bash) tools can probably achieve that sort of edit with reasonable ease...

But are you *sure* you need to change anything?  The documentation you linked actually shows *six* hashes (not four) as the "smallest heading", but three hashes is still "heading smaller than you get with two hashes"...  unless you have more than three levels of heading, why not leave it be?

Comment: No, 3 hashes is not a valid heading.

Comment: By the way, I said 4 ~ I meant 6 mybad :)

Comment: According to the documentation, it is.  Why do you think not?  Note that your sample error had additional hashes at the end, which may not work